# Is it possible to write a binary image to a database using c# and a custom http hander?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

The thinking behind the question is that my image current reads it's data from a custom httphandler that gets the image from the database. I want to be able to use a file upload control to "post" a replacement file back to a "write" handler, updating the database. Then I can refresh my image using javascript to the original "read" handler.

Is this possible?

**Edit**

Thank you for the responses below but I dont think I was clear enough if the question...

I currently have a standard postback model upload process which puts the image into the database and a custom handler to read it back. What I want to know, is can you create a custom http handler to perform the upload so I could asynchronously call the upload handler then refresh the image src to pull it back from the database.

At the moment I am using the IFrame approach to make it appear asynchronous, I just want to know the best practice really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a common use case. Microsoft has a good tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) for creating a file upload handler. From the file upload handler you can get a binary stream that you can pipe into a [SQL command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that you can use to `UPDATE` the database. You'll also want to create a custom [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ff8w4a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that writes something of the correct content type (i.e. `image/jpeg`). When you have the HTTP Handler set up you should be able to access it via a URL with it's identifier (i.e. `<img src="http://localhost/GetImage.ashx?id=123456" />`), so you can use JavaScript to update this.

[Here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/fileupload-control-save-images-database.html) is a great tutorial on this whole process.

Answer (score 0):

In short yes.

You'll want to take your upload control and have it write to a known location either in your file system or write the information that is coming in from the upload control to a Byte Array or an `Image` (System.Drawing.Image) object if you can save it in memory.

Then once that is completed then just execute the SQL to update the image in the database, then if that is successful then you can reload the image on the page using your ajax.

The only problems with this that I could see are:

- How long will the image take to upload an will this be a problem for the end user?
- Handling the cases where things fail and/or the user leaves the page?

You could if you want actually show the image that was uploaded as a replacement before actually saving the image as this would cut out some time, and then on the server side do all of the saving.

Comment: Note the warning at the head of the System.Drawing namespace docs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6ftd89.aspx.  Definite challenges with performance and scaling using System.Drawing.